# Visual Studio Code Intellisense Method Definitions Javascript

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, adobe-brackets

Apparently no one else has wanted this feature, or I'm missing something. Intellisense works as normal, but I'm wondering if I'm missing a setting somewhere, if there is an extension, or if this functionality just isn't offered in VS Code... I would like to have the purpose of the method display when I start typing it as you can see in Adobe Brackets:

[image: Brackets.io]

As opposed to how it shows in VS Code(which just shows the parameter requirements):
[image: VS Code]

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VSCode is able to use the typescript language server to infer some information about the javascript that you're writing. The types for window/document etc are provided by the typescript team.

[Here's](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L5056) where the type information for elements comes from. Compare that with the types for the [document object](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.dom.d.ts#L4124). Notice that the properties here have comments above them, while the element properties do not. Type `document.getElementById` in VSCode, you'll see extra info like you do in brackets:

[image: VSCode screenshot with intellisense]

So for this information to appear about properties on `Element`s, someone would need to go through and add the comments. I have no idea if the typescript team is open to this, though.